# im getting this error while using templateview

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

TypeError at /
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

i just started templateview, CBVs and im getting this issue

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View,TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse

class indexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

Error:

```
TypeError at /
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
Exception Location: /anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py in join, line 80
Python Executable:  /anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/faiq/Desktop/exercise/CBV/advance',
 '/anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/lib/python37.zip',
 '/anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/lib/python3.7',
 '/anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 8 May 2019 21:01:19 +0000
```

Comment: Show the full traceback. The error doesn't seem to be coming from this code.

Comment: Now check ive added the traceback